# cron job fails in gae python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I have a script in Google Appengine that is started every 20 minutes by cron.yaml. This works locally, on my own machine. When I go (manually) to the url which starts the script online, it also works. However, the script always fails to complete online, on Google's instances, when cron.yaml is in charge of starting it.

The log shows no errors, only 2 debug messages:

```
D 2013-07-23 06:00:08.449
type(soup): <class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'> END type(soup)

D 2013-07-23 06:00:11.246
type(soup): <class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'> END type(soup)
```

Here's my script:

```
# coding: utf-8
import jinja2, webapp2, urllib2, re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Article(db.Model):
    content = db.TextProperty()
    datetime = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    companies = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
    url = db.StringProperty()

class Company(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty() 
    ticker = db.StringProperty()

    @property
    def articles(self):
        return Article.gql("WHERE companies = :1", self.key()) 

def companies_key(companies_name=None):
  return db.Key.from_path('Companies', companies_name or 'default_companies')

def articles_key(articles_name=None):
  return db.Key.from_path('Articles', articles_name or 'default_articles')

def scrape():
   companies = memcache.get("companies")
   if not companies:
      companies = Company.all()
      memcache.add("companies",companies,30)
   for company in companies:
      links = links(company.ticker)
      links = set(links)
      for link in links:
          if link is not "None": 
              article_object = Article() 
              text = fetch(link)            
              article_object.content = text
              article_object.url = link
              article_object.companies.append(company.key()) #doesn't work.
              article_object.put()

def fetch(link):
    try:
        html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        soup = bs(html)
    except:
        return "None"
    text = soup.get_text()
    text = text.encode('utf-8')
    text = text.decode('utf-8')
    text = unicode(text)
    if text is not "None": 
        return text
    else: 
        return "None"


def links(ticker):
    url = "https://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=NASDAQ:" + ticker + "&start=10&num=10"
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = bs(html)
    div_class = re.compile("^g-section.*")
    divs = soup.find_all("div", {"class" : div_class})
    links = []
    for div in divs:
        a = unicode(div.find('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")})) 
        link_regex = re.search("(http://.*?)\"",a)
        try:
            link = link_regex.group(1)
            soup = bs(link)
            link = soup.get_text() 
        except:
            link = "None"
        links.append(link)

    return links
```

...and the script's handler in main:

```
class ScrapeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        scrape.scrape()
        self.redirect("/")
```

My guess is that the problem might be the double for loop in the scrape script, but I don't understand exactly why.

**Update:**
Articles are indeed being scraped (as many as there should be), and now there are no log errors, or even debug messages at all. Looking at the log, the cron job seemed to execute perfectly. Even so, Appengine's cron job panel says the cron job failed.

Comment: post your code, maybe something wrong with it. Are those debug messages printed in the cron job handler?

Comment: The debug messages are printed in the gae log, online. This only fails online, in google's own cloud. On my machine, it works without any warnings or debugs.

Comment: HOw do you know it fails to start, the log suggests something is starting.  But probably not running to completion. I would suggest you put more logging in there to see how far the process gets.

Comment: Yes, they do start - they just fail to finish. I will edit the post to reflect that. Also: GAE logs everything by default; there is nothing more there.

Comment: if link is not "None":  << this is wrong, not sure what you expect here, if you want to compare with string, use == , if you want to compare with None, remove double quote.

companies = Company.all()
memcache.add("companies",companies,30) < do you really want to put query object in a cache? Thats really unusual

Comment: Thanks, marcadian. i've changed all the "None"s to Nones. as for the memcache, i might not need that. changed it to companies = Company.All(). The script still fails online, though. To be more specific: the script properly redirects back to the main url, but no new articles have been scraped. When I run it on my own machine, new articles do appear in the db.

Answer (score 0):

I,m pretty sure this error was due to DeadlineExceededError, which I did not run into locally. My scrape() script now does its thing on fewer companies and articles, and does not run into the exceeded deadline.